# Cannot resize Macintosh HD

Tags: macos, disk-utility, partition

I currently have [elementary OS](https://elementary.io/) installed alongside Yosemite. When I try to resize Macintosh HD to give space for a Windows installation, I get the "filesystem support for resizing required" error even though the OS X partition is HFS+. The disks are like this:

```
/dev/disk0
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *251.0 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS Macintosh HD            230.0 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Boot OS X               134.2 MB   disk0s3
   4:       Microsoft Basic Data                         20.7 GB    disk0s4
```

The recovery partition is missing, it seems to me. Anyway, how can I resize Macintosh HD to give space for Windows as well? Boot Camp Assistant would only create a mess and Disk Utility gives the error I mentioned.

**sudo fdisk :**

```
Disk: /dev/disk0    geometry: 30515/255/63 [490234752 sectors]
Signature: 0xAA55
         Starting       Ending
 #: id  cyl  hd sec -  cyl  hd sec [     start -       size]
------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1: EE    0   0   1 - 1023 254  63 [         1 -     409639] <Unknown ID>
*2: AF 1023 254  63 - 1023 254  63 [    409640 -  449218744] HFS+        
 3: AF 1023 254  63 - 1023 254  63 [ 449628384 -     262144] HFS+        
 4: 83 1023 254  63 - 1023 254  63 [ 449892352 -   40341797] Linux files*
```

Comment: Did you already install Windows 7/8 or is disk0s4 just an empty NTFS(/FAT32) volume?

Comment: That is the elementary OS partition.

Comment: Sorry, missed the first sentence somehow.

Comment: I have some questions. You appear to have a OS X recovery partition (disk0s3), but it is to small. Should be about 650 MB and you show 134.2 MB. Can you boot to it? Do you know how? How much free space do you have on your OS X partition? How large of a Windows partition do you what? What version of Windows will you be installing? What is the model of your Mac. Can you add the output of sudo fdisk /dev/disk0 to your question.

Comment: The OS X partition has about 70GB free, I'll be giving 30GB of that to Windows 8.1. It's a MBPr 13".

Comment: The recovery partition does not show up either with alt-boot or in rEFInd.

Comment: You need to put an @David somewhere in you comment, otherwise I will not be notified you posted a comment. In the menu bar on your Mac, select "About this Mac" then click on the "System Report..." button. Find your "Model Identifier" and post as a comment..

Comment: @DavidAnderson It's a MacBookPro 11,1 is that's what your after.

Comment: I debate in my mind which of two approaches to take. The decision would depend on whether you have a external disk large enough to hold the  contents of your OS X partition.

Comment: I would much prefer doing it without formatting the drive, if that's what you're referring to.

Comment: You can not format a drive. You can partition a drive. You can format a partition. I was going to propose neither. There are ways to copy the disk0s2 partition to another disk, reduce the size of the partition, then copy the smaller partition back to the original disk. The other idea would be to do an image backup of disk0s3 to disk0s2, remove partition disk0s3 to see if it fixes the problem. Afterwards, the deleted partition could be restored.

Comment: @DavidAnderson Okay, that "format a drive" thing must be one of the most common mistakes people everywhere make, I've never seen anyone mention anything about it, nice to know! Anyway, is there a command like way to try the resize operation, or do you think it would make no difference? It seems to me that often command line tools work fine even when the GUI versions don't.

Comment: Did you ever fix your problem?

Comment: @DavidAnderson No, I've been too busy working, and I've had to do most of my work with that laptop, so I'd rather not risk it right now. I ended up running Windows in Parallells, but I'll have to fix the partitions eventually.